In haskell, an argument is applied to a function or a function to an argument?
I've been reading some haskell books and they allways say something like "this function is going to be applied to this argument", but I was ignoring this for I thought it was more intuitive to think that the argument were going to be applied to the functions and, maybe, the authors just had a funny way to express themselves, but them I got this error and now I can't ignore this anymore :
<interactive>:y:x: error:
    •No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)   
    •In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

and it states exactly that "maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?", so it looks to me that the function is applied to the argument and not the contrary. So my question is:

Does this make any difference in the way haskell deals with receiving and outputing information behind the scenes ?

For example, if I have a function like add and someone says that 2 is going to be applied to add and then 3 is going to be applied to its output I imagine this :

add 2
(add 2) 3

But if someone says to me that add will be applied to 2 and them its output will them be applied to 3, I imagine this:

2 add
3 (2 add)

Can someone please explain me how this "function being aplied to a argument" works?

What is the difference between the two, besides a somewhat arbitrary grammatical choice? What does 3 (2 add) mean that's different than what (add 2) 3 means?

"thought it was more intuitive to think that the argument were going to be applied to the functions" What?  No.  Functions get applied to arguments.

@LouisWasserman For what it's worth, my reading of this question leaves me with the conclusion that what I mean when I say "X gets applied to Y" and what the OP means when they say "X gets applied to Y" aren't the same. So any answer that uses the terminology "X gets applied to Y" is going to be wrong for one party or the other. There's a deeper question than mere terminology here, but we have to burn through the terminology question to get to it.

This is a terminology question and has nothing to do with Haskell, but indeed you apply a function to its arguments (think about applying an abstract theory to a concrete situation).

@LouisWasserman alright, got it, functions are applied to arguments, but the thing here is that I am not requesting to know a dogma, I want to know how this thing works under the hood. Let me explain what I understand by "apply". Suppose you have a glass of juice and some sugar, for me it doesn't make sense to say "the juice is going to be applied to the sugar", while it makes perfect sense to think that the "sugar is going to be applied to the juice", because the juice is expected to receive arguments, while the argument (sugar) is not meant to receive a function (juice)

@DanielWagner the difference is that the first one doesn't compile, while the second one does

So this is a philosophy question, or a language question. Either way, not Haskell.

I've voted to close as unclear. After reading the question and the comments a few times, I don't really understand exactly what this question is about.

I can see this as asking about https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/07/eval-apply-slides.pdf if I squint, but that's probably making things up.

I'd say "apply sugar to" is the function which is applied to "juice" in your example. Functions are usually verbs in natural language. Neither "sugar" or "juice" on their own make sense as functions to me.

To me "applying functions to arguments" has always been the way I've described it, and which feels the most natural with the ordinary English meaning of the word "apply". GHC obviously uses the word in the same way I do, and I believe this is the more common usage generally.
When I talk about applying one thing to about thing, the thing that I apply is the more "active" participant. For example, I might apply a hammer to a nail, or apply heat to a saucepan, or apply sunscreen to my skin. In each of those cases I think of the hammer, heat, sunscreen, etc as being the one that "causes" the change that results, and the nail, saucepan, skin, etc as being passivlely "acted on" by the thing that was applied to them. If someone told me they applied a nail to a hammer I would think they literally stuck a nail into a hammer (probably using another hammer!).
To use your juice and sugar example from the comments, if you had a glass of juice and you added a spoonful of sugar, I would say you had applied sugar to the juice. The juice is just there, and the sugar is being applied to make it sweeter. I would find it very strange if you described that situation as "applying juice to sugar", or as the juice "receiving the sugar". If you had a bag of sugar and you tipped some juice into it, then I would describe that as "applying juice to sugar", but that seems a much less likely scenario!
So when I talk about programming, I think about the word "apply" in a similar way. If I have a function f = (+1), and I write f 10 I think of 10 as just passively being a number; it's inert, passive. I think of f as the thing that "does something"; it waits until it receives an argument and then figures out what the result of adding one to it is. So I say I apply f to 10; it doesn't seem natural to me to say that I apply 10 to f. f is the hammer, 10 is the nail. Also we already have pass (as in "pass an argument to a function") as an unambiguous verb where the direct object is the argument and the indirect object is the function, so it would be more convenient to save "apply" for the other way around.
It is, however, ultimately arbitrary. It's just a convention. I do often see people talking about "applying arguments to functions", so obviously not everyone finds it as naturally consistent with the ordinary English usage of the word "apply" as I do. It's perfectly understandable that you might have learned "programming talk" from sources that use it in the opposite manner than I do. There is nothing stopping you from using it this way around if you find it more natural; you just have to deal with the fact that other people will sometimes use it differently than you do, and figure out what they mean from context.
So there's not really anything to explain about "how it works", you just memorise which way around it goes and that's it. It's purely an English language issue of how we talk about things, and has nothing to do with any implementation questions behind the scenes.
In an idealistic sense I think it should be used consistently one way around (and obviously my way is the correct way ), because functions are also values and can be passed as arguments to other functions. So if we just say that "apply" can be meant either way around as each author prefers, then in some contexts "apply f to g" is ambiguous (unlike in "apply f to 10", were it's very unlikely that the author meant 10 f). That means we have to be more verbose to be clear, saying things like "apply the function f to an argument g". To avoid needing that verbosity we have to agree to a convention that one way is correct English and the other is incorrect. So while I am generally in favour of descriptive rather than prescriptive linguistics, picking one way as correct is useful here, and I would argue that there are good enough reasons to prefer "apply a function to an argument", as GHC does.
But the reality is that it is used both ways and I just have to live with the occasional mental friction of seeing used the other way around. You will also just have to live with GHC using the word "apply" differently than you do.

Since nobody has mentioned this yet: in Haskell (and more generally in mathematics) you can also write ($ 10) f, which is applying application to 10 (or evaluation at 10) to f, hence ultimately applying f to 10. So there's a bit of a duality there which could justify swapping the words around.
